# Change a String that has a link in it

Tags: json, swift, xcode

```
let profile_pic_url_hd = user["profile_pic_url_hd"] as! String
self.imgURL = "\(profile_pic_url_hd)"
```

`self.imgURL` is a link and it is a string. The link is, for example:

```
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/19121160_1328742810566926_6482637033138290688_a.jpg
```

Does anyone knows how to change this link to:

```
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/19121160_1328742810566926_6482637033138290688_a.jpg
```

In other words, without `/s320x320/`.

Comment: Why are you assigning `"\(profile_pic_url_hd)"` to `self.imgURL` instead of directly assigning `profile_pic_url_hd`?

Comment: `profile_pic_url_hd` is the name of the Json class or whatever it's called

Comment: No it's not. It's a variable of type `String`. Just do: `self.imgURL = profile_pic_url_hd`

Comment: It wont work if i do it your way.. It works my way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `URLComponents`, split up the URL's path, and rebuild a new URL.

```
let urlstr = "https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s320x320/19121160_1328742810566926_6482637033138290688_a.jpg"
if var comps = URLComponents(string: urlstr) {
    var path = comps.path
    var pathComps = path.components(separatedBy: "/")
    pathComps.remove(at: 2) // this removes the s320x320
    path = pathComps.joined(separator: "/")
    comps.path = path
    if let newStr = comps.string {
        print(newStr)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/19121160_1328742810566926_6482637033138290688_a.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you so much!